# Connecting AWS TLS certificate with Azure App Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, ssl

I have a public certificate I created on AWS certificate manager. I then have an app I hosted on Azure App services. Azure provides a TLS URL on `my_domain.azurewebsites.net`.

I want to connect my domain certificate (`my_domain.com`) on AWS to the TLS URL on Azure. I have been able to make the connection, however, when I go to `my_domain.com`, the connection is not secure.

Please how can I get this done? Thanks.

Comment: Your question lacks details. You have to provide all the details of your setup. How did you verify ssl cert? How do you test the connection?

Comment: Thanks Marcin. SSL certificate was created on AWS certificate manager. And it's configured fine.

Say I have an SSL cert for my_domain.com, it shows that it has been issued on AWS. The connection now is to the URL I have on azure. When I go to my_domain.com, it redirects me to my app on Azure but the connection is insecure.

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is how to get Azure to use your custom domain name